# c++ - Failing to read a binary file

Tags: c++, file, io, binary, binaryfiles

I have a binary file that should contain mostly raw byte data, that is being generated and processed in class `CubeState`. I ran a few tests and it seems that writing process is ok. The only problem I get is that sometimes it writes down the 0x00 character and whenever that occurs, I receive cropped or no data. This is the example of how I write/read.

```
CubeState currentParent = CubeState();
char* buf = new char[10];
std::ofstream ostr = std::ofstream("parents", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
ostr.write(currentParent.getContent().c_str(), 10);
ostr.close();

std::ifstream istr("parents", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);     
istr.read(buf, 10);
istr.close();
currentParent = CubeState(buf);
```

`currentParent.getContent().c_str()` in default form will return string of characters as follows - 0x00 0x01 0x05 0x0B 0x17 and so on.

EDIT

`CubeState` is the black box that is working. If you need another example - here you go:

```
char* buf = new char[4];
std::ofstream ostr = std::ofstream("parents", std::ios::out | 
std::ios::binary);
ostr.write("" + (char)0 + (char)1 + (char)5 + (char)11, 4);
ostr.close();

std::ifstream istr("parents", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);     
istr.read(buf, 4);
istr.close();
std::cout << buf << std::endl;
```

Output will be empty and if you check `buf` in runtime - it is also empty

Comment: `write` will write 10 characters no matter how long the string returned from `c_str()` is. Is this really what you want? It is undefined behavior if the string is not actually that long.

Comment: What would be interesting to see is how you process buf within your CubeState? Maybe your code checks to see if the char in buf is not a null character (which it would be because you are writing 0x00}, then it would stop processing beyond that giving you the impression that the data was cropped or not read.

Comment: Output of `getContent()` is always string with 10 characters.

I checked `buf` in runtime, it was empty.

Comment: If the size is not the issue, then I don't see a problem except that you are possibly processing the `char` pointer wrong inside `CubeState(buf)`, not taking into account that it is a binary buffer rather than a null-terminated C string.

Comment: The bug is in the code you haven't shown us. If I _fill in the blanks_ it will work just fine.

Comment: This is not a [mcve].  The first thing any programmer would have done is *hard-code* the string, and not call a function such as `CubeState` to see if the general idea works.  You've posted code where we don't know what `CubeState` does, whether it has bugs, etc.  Take the time to write a small `main` function that does exactly the same thing with known, hard-coded string data.  If that works correctly, then and only then do you introduce function calls.

Comment: Thanks for the input, added example

Comment: You claim that `CubeState` is working, but if we assume your strings are written and read with the correct length, starting from the same positions in the file, then the error has to be in `CubeState` because there is nothing wrong with the code. The `cout` would show `buf` as empty, because (like many standard library functions), it will assume that `buf`, being of type `char*`, is a zero-terminated string, which (as the name says) ends at the first zero. If you want to resolve this issue show what you are doing in `CubeState` and make sure you use no function assuming `buf` to be a C string.

Answer (score 0):

`CubeState` was prone to generate outputs that started with /0, i.e. `(char)0`. This caused the issue - the returned strings were assumed empty. 
I will open another question regarding this later once I will have an adequate code snippet that will demonstrate my concern properly. 
If you're still interested in contents of `CubeState.getContent()` - here it is

```
class CubeState {
private:
state = {
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26
};
const int av[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 0, 10, 6, 11, 7 },
corners[] = { 0, 2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 24, 26 },
sides[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25 };

... 

std::string getContent() {
std::bitset<80> container(0);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    int temp = av[state[corners[i]]];
    container[i * 3] = temp % 2;
    temp >>= 1;
    container[i * 3 + 1] = temp % 2;
    temp >>= 1;
    container[i * 3 + 2] = temp;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    int temp = av[state[sides[i]]];
    container[i * 4 + 24] = temp % 2;
    temp >>= 1;
    container[i * 4 + 25] = temp % 2;
    temp >>= 1;
    container[i * 4 + 26] = temp % 2;
    temp >>= 1;
    container[i * 4 + 27] = temp;
}

int temp = parent;  
container[72] = temp % 2;
temp >>= 1;
container[73] = temp % 2;
temp >>= 1;
container[74] = temp % 2;
temp >>= 1;
container[75] = temp;
std::string result;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    result += std::bitset<8>(container.to_string().substr(i, i * 8)).to_ulong() + 1;

return result;
}
```